# Insert a comma after a fixed number of characters or a space

Tags: bash, sed

I'm wondering if there is an option to insert an "or" within sed, I need to convert a txt file to a csv file, the thing is my first column values can be up to 30 characters (minimun 1 character) if this happens the value in the next column start after the last character, otherwise space(s) are added, therefore I need to validate both cases before insert a comma, otherwise the comma might be inserted in the incorrect place.

Example:

```
column 1                      column 2
column1-value-up-to-30-charssscolumn2-value
column1-second-value          column2-second-value
column1-third-value-value     column2-thrid-value-value
```

Expected result (comma inserted after each value, even column names)

```
column 1,column 2
column1-value-up-to-30-charsss,column2-value
column1-second-value,column2-second-value
column1-third-value-value,column2-thrid-value-value
```

Therefore, I cannot always used sed to look for and empty space (like in value one) because the comma will be inserted at the end of the value in column 2

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I've included an example as well.

Answer (score 0):

With your given input, maybe something like this?

```
sed -E 's/^(.{1,30})(.{1,})$/\1,\2/;s/[[:space:]]{2,}//' file.txt
```

---

It seems the `-E` flag is not define/required by [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html), but it should be on both `GNU` and `BSD` variants. A portable `sed` syntax without the `-E` would be.

```
sed 's/^\(.\{1,30}\)(.\{1,\}\)$/\1,\2/;s/[[:space:]]\{2,\}//' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/./\n&/31;s/\s*\n/,/' file
```

Insert a newline before character 31 and then replace the newline and any spaces before it with a comma.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use GNU awk (for `FIELDWIDTHS`) for this instead of sed:

```
$ awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="30 *" -v OFS=',' '{sub(/ +$/,"",$1)} 1' file
column 1,column 2
column1-value-up-to-30-charssscolumn2-value
column1-second-value,column2-second-value
column1-third-value-value,column2-thrid-value-value
```